# LMS Lectures on Geometric Langlands

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, soft-question, geometric-langlands, online-resources

Everybody knows how insightful are David Ben-Zvi talks (and comments/answers here on mathoverflow). I was trying to watch the [LMS 2007 Lecture Series on Geometric Langlands](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/benzvi/GRASP/Oxford.html) by David, supposedly made available via [GRASP Lectures](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/benzvi/GRASP.html), but the server is down or no longer exists.

Some of the GRASP lectures are available on the iTunes Podcasts of the University of Texas Austin, but unfortunately not these ones.

Does anybody know where else to find them online or did anyone downloaded them back then and could, please, make them available to the community again?

Comment: the web page is mirrored at the Wayback machine, but apparently the mp3 files are not available (I don't have the plugin, so I'm not certain): https://web.archive.org/web/20150321074051/http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/benzvi/GRASP/Oxford.html

Comment: Works for me: http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/benzvi/GRASP/Oxford.html

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes, I've tried that before, but at no avail.

Comment: @IgorRivin What do you mean it works for you? Can you watch the videos and/or download the mp3's?

Comment: Why don’t you email DBZ directly? His address is on his papers. Maybe @davidben-zvi will work too.

Comment: @Aaron Did that already a few months ago :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The videos from the LMS lectures and all of the GRASP videos are now available again from the links you gave (for download, not streaming). Many apologies for their long hiatus offline and many thanks for your enthusiasm and persistence!! Please do email me for broken links etc., and I will update the site with some more recent materials.

Edit June 2022: The links have moved, the GRASP videos (including the LMS lectures) are [available for download here.](https://media.ma.utexas.edu/video/GRASP/streaming-server/math-grasp/)

While we're at it (and to compensate for these lectures being such a pain to track down), here is a link (hopefully even a working one?!?) to videos of my entire Spring 2021 graduate course [From Maxwell to Langlands](https://utexas.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Sessions/List.aspx?folderID=60f2affd-9683-4426-8552-acb300082333) (or some name to that effect) about the Langlands program and electric-magnetic duality. Notes for these lectures are available from [Arun Debray](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~adebray/lecture_notes/) and [Jackson Van Dyke](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/vandyke/) (and the dream is to eventually turn these into a book, but I wouldn't hold my breath).

Comment: Hurray! Thank you David for this invaluable source of resources!

Comment: These links aren't working again; since I was strongly recommended I watch these lectures by someone who works in geometric representation theory, I was wondering if there is any chance that they would be up again soon. Thank you!

Comment: Many thanks for the new stuff! Yes, it works, and it is marvelous!